# Logging values from currently focused textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let us assume that I have many `textarea` elements on my page, and my goal is to log the value of current `textarea` element that I am typing on.

I have managed to write the code that does just that, but the problem is that when type text in one `textarea`, and then switch to another and type in that for a while, when I come back to the first one, I get two `.keyup()` methods attached to that element. So I get two logs of that `textarea` value.

```
$( "body" ).click( function( event ) {
  let element = event.target
  if( element.nodeName === "TEXTAREA" ){
    if($(element).focus()){
      $(element).keyup(function(){      
        console.log(element.value)   
      })
    }else {
      $(element).unbind( 'keyup' )
    }  
  }
});
```

What do I need to do to remove that method stacking?

Comment: I see 2 solutions. You can unbind the event listener if the element goes out of focus (the `blur` event should be what you need to listen for here). But probably best would be to rewrite the code so that all keyup event listeners are attached to the textareas on page load (rather than doing it in response to a focus eveng as you have here).

Comment: try `$("textarea").focus(function(){ $(this).... });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never attach event inside another event because when the first fired the one inside will be attached another time and so on.

I suggest attaching the `input` event directly to the `textarea`'s instead of `keyup` and nested events, so with the helps of `this` keyword you will get the current changed `textarea` element, like :

```js
$("textarea").on('input', function(event) {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: `You should never attach event inside another event` is ringing in my head now. Thanks for elegant solution and great explanation